# Adding a hyperlink on a shape in Google Spread Sheet

Tags: hyperlink, google-sheets-api

I need to add a hyperlink on a shape in Google spread sheet. The shape is drawn using Drawing option in insert menu. When I click the shape (which is hyperlinked), it needs to go to another tab available in the same spreadsheet.

Is it possible to do make this?

Thanks

Comment: Unfortunately, I thought that your goal cannot be directly achieved. So, I proposed a workaround. Please confirm it. If that was not useful, I apologize.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

#### Issue and workaround:

In the current stage, unfortunately, the drawing images on Spreadsheet cannot be managed by Sheets API, and also, the hyperlink cannot be added to the drawing.

But, fortunately, I thought that there is a workaround.

- About managing the drawings, when Google Apps Script is used, this can be achieved.
- Unfortunately, the hyperlink cannot be added to the drawing by Google Apps Script. But, from `When I click the shape (which is hyperlinked), it needs to go to another tab available in the same spreadsheet.`, in this case, I thought that this can be achieved using Google Apps Script.

When these are reflected in the flow, please do the following flow.

#### 1. Prepare a sample drawing.

From `The shape is drawn using drawing option in insert menu.`, please create a new sample drawing on the Spreadsheet.

#### 2. Prepare sample script.

Please copy and paste the following script to the script editor of Spreadsheet and save the script.

```js
function sample() {
  const sheetName = "Sheet2"; // Please set the target sheet name you want to move.
  SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheetByName(sheetName).activate();
}
```

#### 3. Assign function.

Please select the drawing on the Spreadsheet and please click the 3 dots at the top right of the drawing. And, please select "Assign script". And, please input `sample` to "What script do you want to assign?", and click the "OK" button. [Ref](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/menus#clickable_images_and_drawings_in_google_sheets)

By this, when you click the drawing as a button, the script is run, and "Sheet2" is activated.

#### References:

- [activate()](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/sheet#activate())
- [Clickable images and drawings in Google Sheets](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/menus#clickable_images_and_drawings_in_google_sheets)

Comment: Hi Tanaike, thanks very much for your valuable time to write the reply. This was much useful for me!. One additional request...  I have this requirement: In one of the tabs (sheet), I have many shapes whose label (a.k.a: displayed text) is available as another tab in the same book. Whenever I click the shape, that takes me to the respective tab. I am just trying to come up with a single function which takes the shape label as argument and takes me to the sheet. Thanks!

Comment: @user3103957 Thank you for replying. About `I am just trying to come up with a single function which takes the shape label as argument and takes me to the sheet`, in the current stage, when a button on the Spreadsheet is clicked, the argument cannot be given. And also, it cannot be known which button is clicked from Google Apps Script. By this, in a current workaround, it is required to use each function name for every button. In this case, how about posting it to [Google Issue Tracker](https://developers.google.com/issue-tracker)?

Comment: @user3103957 For example, as a workaround, how about using the wrapper functions for using arguments? When it supposes that the main function is `const main = value => do something using value.`, the functions for each button are `const function1 = _ => main("sample argument 1");`, `const function2 = _ => main("sample argument 1");`,,,. If this was not useful, I apologize.